# How to search output of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, search

I am trying find any typos in user zip code entries.
We have a file with all zip codes that helpdesk use when creating users.

Using `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties POBox | select POBox` I am able to get all PObox entry for all users.

Next step is to check zip codes in the text file glocodes and if entry does not match it should output to console.

```
$GLCODES= Get-Content glcodes.txt
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties POBox |
    select POBox |
    ? {$_.POBox -notcontains $GLCODES}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have the operands in switched places.
As far as I get from syntax, it should be:

```
{ $GLCODES -notcontains $_.POBox }
```

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> <Reference-values> -contains <Test-value>
> ```

[Microsoft docs:: About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Starting with PowerShell v3 you could also use `<Test-value> -in <Reference-values>`.